# What other ways are there to avoid 'assembly leaking' than friend assemblies?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

In big solutions - especially monolithic or module-lithic ones - it can be hard to prevent others and yourself from accidentally referencing an assembly in another assembly where it should not be used at all. That's what I mean by 'assembly leaking'.

It seems odd to me that most multi-layer software designs use `public` to expose classes, interfaces, or whatever to another project/assembly.

For example in [CleanArchitecture](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture) all classes and interfaces of the infrastructure project are `public` yet they are only used by the web project. So how could one restrict the use of these `public` infrastructure classes to be only used in the web project?

One interesting .NET feature to accomplish such a restriction could be [Friend Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/friend), but I don't think this should be used in every context. So what other ways are there?

Comment: `InternalsVisibleTo` is more of a hack to get classes exposed to outside projects, mainly for unit tests. I don't understand why you are concerned that `public` makes a class visible outside its project though, that is the entire point of making it public. There is an argument that transitive references can be a bad thing and make object leak places where they shouldn't go, but you can disable that with `<DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>true</DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>` in the csproj files.

Comment: part 1/2: Thanks for your response @DavidG. To the first part about `InternalsVisibleTo`: sure it is often used that way (and it often is a hacky workaround applied this way), but I think that's exactly because it isn't understood how it actually should be used. As the FAQ for C++ states you should always keep `private` things `private` and use friend assemblies as a replacement for `public` things that don't need to be public. To the second part: the thing is that most things for example a DbContext of an infrastructure project do not need to be public. Only the API layer needs to inject it.

Comment: part 2/2 So why would the DbContext need to be public? The least privilege principle is for what I know a really good practice to follow because someone could easily accidentally use the DbContext in another project where it should not be used. Might sound unrealistic in this scenario, but scale the project up to 10 different projects with 50 devs working on it and it won't take too long for the first dependencies to get leaked into layers where they shouldn't be used.

Comment: Well you don't need to make a DbContext public though, you can make it private and only expose it's features via an interface, and set up that DI via a method that lives inside the same project. Nothing outside then needs to know anything about the context class.

Comment: Can you provide an example or a more detailed explanation of how to do that? When you create an interface in the same project as the DbContext lives in, what benefit would the interface provide? When you put the method for dependency injection into the same project as well, then the project would need to know of the dependency container you're using, that means depending upon the presentation/api layer? Sure you could then abstract that, but then both the infrastructure and presentation layer would depend on that abstraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is what it is. From the perspective of an assembly (the root level entity): we have the scope `internal` that restricts the visibility of a type to the current assembly.
If a type must be visible outside its assembly, then the type's scope is `public`.

From the perspective of the assembly, everything that is outside the assembly, external, is public. This definition makes perfect sense.
With the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` you can break this rule by qualifying an assembly as friend/exception.

Why isn't this used more often? We can only guess. But there are also facts to consider. At least we can say that `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` comes with all the disadvantages that attribute based type or member configuration brings.
Some don't have this feature on their mind unless they find themselves in a situation where they have to increase the visibility of `internal` types and members only to implement a unit test.
Some consider it a bad smell and avoidable by proper class/assembly design. Because there must be/is a better way to solve this problem without sacrificing valuable design principles.
Some would argue that `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` scales bad because when you have a new assembly that needs access to the internal type you have to decorate the assembly with a new `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` and re-deploy it. Thats not nice at all.
Some could think that `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` is kind of an emergency button for developers that don't know proper class design or don't know their language well enough.

Most reasons are highly subjective.

From experience we can tell that properly designed classes don't make the use of `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` necessary (except for unit test assemblies).

We *are* able to value information hiding and avoid defining our internal types `public`.
One major drawback is that the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute makes *all* internal APIs public to the friend assembly.
We no longer have control over what the friend assembly is allowed to access. The assembly and its friend assembly are treated like they were virtually a single assembly (in terms of member and type accessibility).
However, assuming that they are two logical assemblies for a reason, then the effect of exposing the complete internals (types and members declared as `internal`) is not desirable.
If this degree of visibility *is* desirable, then the two assemblies likely should be merged instead. It all starts with the design of the assemblies.

When `InternalsVisibleTo` bypasses and breaks our original design decisions (those APIs were `internal` for a good reason), then we must carefully evaluate whether the use of `InternalsVisibleTo` is *really* reasonable or could/should be avoided by improving the design in the first place.

I suggest changing the focus of your question: what can we do to avoid the use of the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` attribute?
Answering this question also allows us to understand better why `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` attribute is not really necessary except for edge cases: that's why friend assemblies are realized using the attribute and not via e.g. a `friend` keyword. If it is not really necessary it makes sense that we don't find it often. Edge cases are rare by definition.

## Example

For example, if you create a library, you have a public API and the internal business logic of that library.
Our goal is to avoid the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` attribute to improve extensibility (improve maintainability).

To solve our problem of having types that depend on types defiend in different assemblies we can pick one of the following solution or a combine them:

### Use proper assembly design

You could move the public API to its own assembly and move the internal logic to the internal assembly. Of course, having everything in the same assembly works too. However, the key is to move all internal dependencies to the same assembly and specify all these types as `internal`.

Well-structured assemblies strive to contain all their internal types i.e. don't have external dependencies.
In other words, it all depends on how you design assemblies.

One can come up with different assembly design rules.
You can use assemblies to group types by the first letter of the type name.
You can use responsibilities of types to define assemblies.
You can use a deployment scheme.
You can define assemblies based on some architectural definitions.

However, you can also define assemblies based on type scope and the dependency graph of the types.
This seems to be the most sophisticated approach. But it requires deeper understanding of the class level responsibilities of the application, framework or library.

Proper design must be the foundation. If the design is bad, you open the door for a lot of smell to creep in.

### Use `protected class`

You can also make use of the `protected` access modifier, which allows a class defined in a different assembly to subclass it. This is kind of the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` attribute behavior achieved via inheritance. This language/compiler feature allows us to have a `protected` base class in one assembly and the derived subclass in another assembly.
This is useful if we want to make internals visible only to those types that extend our e.g. library. This is the most common case that would make the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` useful. But it's more elegant and scales better.

See the following example to see how we can use `protected class` to make internal functionality visible to different assemblies, that extend the defining assembly, without exposing the types to our public API.

This requires to define the `protected` type as a nested type:

**Library.dll**

```cs
public abstract class LibraryBaseClass
{
  // The type is not directly visible via the public library API
  protected class LibraryHelperClass
  {
    // The functionality is not directly accessible via the public library API
    public void MemberIsOnlyVisibleToTypesThatExtendLibraryBaseClass()
    {
      // Access library internal features
    }
  }

  public abstract void LibraryExtensionCode();
}
```

```cs
internal class AnotherLibraryClass
{
  public void DoSomething()
  {
    // INVALID CODE: 
    // LibraryHelperClass is inaccessible due to the protection level.
    // AnotherLibraryClass would have to subclass LibraryBaseClass
    // in order to be able to access LibraryHelperClass (not optimal for some cases).
    var internalLibraryHelper = new LibraryHelperClass();
  }
}
```

**B.dll**

```cs
// We have to subclass LibraryBaseClass in order to get access to the LibraryHelperClass class. It's hidden from the public API but visible if we extend library code 
public class LibraryExtension : LibraryBaseClass 
{
  public override void LibraryExtensionCode()
  {
    // Add extended functionality

    // We have access to the "internal" type similar to InternalsVisbleToAttribute.
    // The difference is that in order to become a friend of the assembly "Library.dll" 
    // we must implement library code, which is what we usually intent to do 
    // when we believe we need InternalsVisibleToAttribute
    var internalHelperClass = new LibraryHelperClass();
  
    // Execute some internal library code
    internalHelperClass.MemberIsOnlyVisibleToTypesThatExtendLibraryBaseClass();
}
```

### Use `protected internal class`

Then there is `protected internal` which is a combination of `protected` and `internal`: the type is visible to all types in the same assembly but only visible to subclasses defined in different assemblies.

For example, while in the previous example the nested `LibraryHelperClass` is visible to subclasses of `LibraryBaseClass` it won't be visible directly to the defining assembly itself - except for subclasses of `LibraryBaseClass`.

The `protected` access modifier requires the caller to be a subclass of `LibraryBaseClass`.
Adding `internal` will also allow the current assembly to reference the nested `LibraryHelperClass` class without having to subclass `LibraryBaseClass`.
`protected internal` does not change the accessibility for external DLLs. For external DLLs the `protected` is relevant (as it lifts the `internal` access restriction):

**Library.dll**

```cs
public abstract class LibraryBaseClass
{
  // The type is not directly visible via the public library API
  protected class LibraryHelperClass
  {
    // The functionality is not directly accessible via the public library API
    public void MemberIsOnlyVisibleToTypesThatExtendLibraryBaseClass()
    {
      // Access library internal features
    }
  }

  public abstract void LibraryExtensionCode();
}
```

```cs
internal class AnotherLibraryClass
{
  public void DoSomething()
  {
    // The protection level of 'protected internal' now enables other types 
    // of the current assembly to treat the LibraryHelperClass 
    // as a common internal type.
    // No subclassing of LibraryBaseClass is required for assembly types.
    var internalLibraryHelper = new LibraryBaseClass.LibraryHelperClass();
  }
}
```

**B.dll**
However, nothing has changed for the external assemblies.
They still have to subclass the `LibraryBaseClass` in order to get access to the internal `LibraryHelperClass`

```cs
// We have to subclass LibraryBaseClass in order to get access to the LibraryHelperClass class. It's hidden from the public API but visible if we extend library code 
public class LibraryExtension : LibraryBaseClass 
{
  public override void LibraryExtensionCode()
  {
    // Add extended functionality

    // We have access to the "internal" type similar to InternalsVisbleToAttribute.
    // The difference is that in order to become a friend of the assembly "Library.dll" 
    // we must implement library code, which is what we usually intent to do 
    // when we believe we need InternalsVisibleToAttribute
    var internalHelperClass = new LibraryHelperClass();
  
    // Execute some internal library code
    internalHelperClass.MemberIsOnlyVisibleToTypesThatExtendLibraryBaseClass();
}
```

We can see that we can achieve similar behavior without using the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` attribute using the `protected internal` access modifier.
Both solution, the `protected internal` access modifier and proper assembly design, are far easier to maintain then using the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` attribute.

It's always good to know the language features in order to write better code and develop better applications.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. There are a few points to address. First to the "`InternalsVisibleToAttribute` is harder to maintain": I don't understand why it should be harder than your proposed solutions that involve refactoring the whole code base or at least, if it's a green field project, necessitate writing more code versus just using `internal` instead of `public` and adding a few `InternalsVisibleTo` elements to csproj files. Second, your solutions would probably lead to a better assembly design, but they still make it possible to use the classes of one assembly in any other assembly

Comment: Also to "I suggest changing the focus of your question: what can we do to avoid the use of the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` attribute?": my question is directed towards the other side. I could rephrase it to "Is there a reason why using friend assemblies to reinforce assembly separation be avoided?"
And to clarify: I am not proposing to change anything from `private` to `internal`, which is a bad practice sometimes used for unit testing, I am talking about using `internal` instead of `public` so we have a lower class exposure and only consciously by using the `InternalsVisibleTo`...

Comment: ...exposing classes only to the assemblies where they should be used.

Comment: The `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` *is* harder to maintain, because you would have to decorate an already compiled and deployed/shipped assembly - *every time* you add a new assembly that requires the elevation. This is basically a breaking change as you would have to rebuild and deploy/ship the assembly.

Comment: On the other hand, increasing the visibility of a type (e.g., from `internal` to `protected internal`) is not a breaking change. You don't want to introduce breaking changes at all cost. This cost can be more work behind the scenes. It might appear easier to refactor the code by decorating the assemblies with the attribute. but this is not a long-term solution (because you have to repeat it over and over again if you need to give access to a different assembly). Changing the access modifiers is a one-time modification.

Comment: My main argument is that you usually only need to introduce friend assemblies to enable them to access internal library code. The classic scenario is that the friend assembly extends the library and to do this needs to access internals like helpers etc. We generally extend functionality by extending a class. `protected internal` leverages this scenario as it allows an external class to subclass and extend existing behavior by providing access to a carefully designed `protected internal` API.

Comment: Of course, the internal features exposed by the `protected internal` type are visible to every class that hass access to the `protected internal` base type through inheritance. What the extending class can see and how it can use the exposed API depends on the class design. If you can't help it, then you can always decide to use the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`.

Comment: *"Is there a reason why using friend assemblies to reinforce assembly separation be avoided?"* - As mentioned before, long-term maintainability. And the les control who can access what internals. When you use `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` then the friend assembly has access to *all* `internal` APIs. You basically have converted all access modifiers `internal` to `public`. You have to decide if this doesn't matter to you. `protected internal` gives you more control. You can precisely define what internals are visible.

Comment: If you care about proper class design which also includes information hiding then you care about being as restrictive as possible in terms of member accessibility. Then you would use `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` with care. If you design your classes and APIs carefully `protected internal` can be a graceful solution.

Comment: Introducing a new assembly is a breaking change no matter, if you use `InternalsVisibleTo` or not. Also, you're not introducing new assemblies daily. It should occur rarely on the other hand you're working with the assemblies daily, so introducing more complex classes is not harder to maintain from your point of view? I'm not sure if we are talking about the same thing when you say `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`. I am talking about using the `<ItemGroup> <InternalsVisibleTo Include="OtherProject" /></ItemGroup>` not setting in on the class level or something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257107/discussion-between-rene-and-bioniccode).